# Java Android SetText Doesnt Work

Tags: java, android

My Client class should give the values of x_atual,y_atual etc... I tried to debug the code by commenting the last two lines of code and the settext doesnt even work. The TextViews still have the same defeault text.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView x_atual,y_atual,x_desejado,y_desejado,ola;
Cliente myClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    x_atual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_atual);
    y_atual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_atual);
    x_desejado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_desej);
    y_desejado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y_desej);
    ola = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    x_atual.setText("0");
    y_atual.setText("0");
    x_desejado.setText("0");
    y_desejado.setText("0");
    ola.setText("ola");

    myClient = new Cliente(x_atual,y_atual,x_desejado,y_desejado);
    myClient.execute();
}


}
```

I have multiple fragments but I dont think it's that.

```
public class Cliente extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    TextView x_atual,y_atual,x_desejado,y_desejado;
    Scanner r;
    String[] valores = new String[4];

    public Cliente(String addr, int port) {
        //super();
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    public Cliente(TextView x_atual,TextView y_atual, TextView x_desejado, TextView y_desejado) {
        //super();
        this.x_atual = x_atual;
        this.y_atual = y_atual;
        this.x_desejado = x_desejado;
        this.y_desejado = y_desejado;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            r = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        valores[0] = r.nextLine();
        valores[1] = r.nextLine();
        valores[2] = r.nextLine();
        valores[3] = r.nextLine();
        publishProgress(valores[0],valores[1],valores[2],valores[3]);
try {
    Thread.sleep(60);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        x_atual.setText(valores[0]);
        y_atual.setText(valores[1]);
        x_desejado.setText(valores[2]);
        y_desejado.setText(valores[3]);
       super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your client class as well?

Comment: sureeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Generally, passing views into an AsyncTask is a poor design. You could follow this suggestion here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Comment: Your code not set dstAddress and dstPort. So NPE will caused at `r.nextLine();`. And I guess `onPostExecute` will never be called.

Comment: I get dstadress and port from the labels. It's connecting well.

Comment: Mmm, there is no code that set `dstAddress' and `dstPort`.

Comment: There is. On the MainActivity. It works correctly and I get the data from the server. Look my other post please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929109/android-java-asyntask-never-calls-onprogressupdate

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you call setText, the view creations have not been finished yet.

```
x_atual.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            x_atual.setText("hi!");
        }
    });
```

Do this for each one.

This waits until the view is finished, then it will setText.