# Textview setText doesnt show

Tags: android

`setText("hello")` doesn't work

I have it in my `onCreate`

```
TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stuff);

tx.setText("hello");
```

It stays blank.

Comment: Show your full code

Comment: No one would be able to help you unless you show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an old answer: [Java Android SetText Doesnt Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927921/java-android-settext-doesnt-work/38929692#38929692)

try:

```
tx.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tx.setText("hello");
    }
});
```

Sometimes the TextView hasn't finished being created, so your setText() won't apply yet. This makes sure it's done after it's finished creation.

Comment: sometimes it was just that extra five servings of ice cream, that made you a bit slower, anyways, don't relay on it, the `post` will wait for it.